# CSS Button - text not on button

Tags: css

I did create some CSS buttons with the help of http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/ but for some reason the text is not completely on the button but going through the bottom of it.
[image]

I think this is due to some of my main CSS ? Is there some way I can override that, and which property would I have to use ?

Css Code:

```
  <style type="text/css">
.classname {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fce2c1;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fce2c1;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fce2c1;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffc477), color-stop(1, #fb9e25) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffc477 5%, #fb9e25 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffc477', endColorstr='#fb9e25');
    background-color:#ffc477;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #eeb44f;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #cc9f52;
}.classname:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #fb9e25), color-stop(1, #ffc477) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #fb9e25 5%, #ffc477 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fb9e25', endColorstr='#ffc477');
    background-color:#fb9e25;
}.classname:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
/* This imageless css button was generated by CSSButtonGenerator.com */
</style>
```

Comment: what's the CSS that you think may be conflicting?

Comment: set line-height = the height of the button

Comment: I would have used developer tools or fire bug to fix this.

Comment: I can't really tell, it's a massive CSS file from a template. setting `line-height` doesn't do anything, if I set it with `!important` it just moves around the button but not the text

Comment: line-height on the button

Comment: @Ark setting it in css doesn't work, setting it on the button directly `style="line-height: 22px;"` doesn't work too.

Comment: looks like a possible padding issue. What are you applying the class to?

Comment: a button: `<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" class="classname">`

Comment: Well how could I figure out what other css is associated with it ? Like I said, there's a massive css file (which is formatted horribly). Is there no other way to just override other properties?

Comment: Ah well, I found it thanks to Firebug, in the other css file input height was set to 17px, thanks everyone.

Comment: Yup. Control+Shift+I in Firefox is how I find most of my css issues.

Comment: Move your style rules to the bottom of the style sheet.  If they start working then you have a conflict above somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the code above, see this JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fQ6h7/ must be something else in your stylesheet, probably a class with the same name or something like that? Or something applied to all buttons?

```
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" class="classname">
```